# Mediation analysis with categorical outcome

Tags: statistics, regression, categorical-data, multinomial

I want to run a mediation analysis to see the effect of **E**xposure to a pollutant (continuous) to types of **C**ancer (categorical with 4 levels-types of cancer) via a **B**lood biomarker as the mediator (continuous). So the mediation diagram would be something like this:

**E** -> **B** -> **C**

For the mediation variable I run the linear regression analysis:

```
med.fit <- lm(blood_biomarker~exposure+age+sex, data=demographics)
```

but when it comes to the outcome variable, I read from the docs that the only appropriate analysis is multinomial regression analysis such as:

```
out.fit <- multinom(cancer_type~blood_biomarker+exposure+age+sex, data=demographics)
```

then again the **mediate** function won't work with the multinom class object as input.

```
#this doesn't work
med.out<-mediate(med.fit,out.fit, treat="exposure", mediator="blood_biomarker")
```

All above models are simplified for my example. there are more confounders than age and sex

I am new to mediation analysis and I think my problem is more on the regression method required than the code itself. Is there a way to do the same analysis using glm() or lm() (or any other that produces an object recognized from mediate function) for this kind of data?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that the exposure are continuous data. Try the package [`medflex`](https://github.com/jmpsteen/medflex) for continuous exposure (version 4.2).

> Steen J, Loeys T, Moerkerke B, Vansteelandt S. 2017. medflex : An R
>   Package for Flexible Mediation Analysis using Natural Effect Models.
>   J. Stat. Softw. 76.

However, I am not sure the mediator can be continuous, it may also be a problem for the analysis.